# Rephrasing what this proof is asking

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, absolute-value

I am new to proofs and am still struggling to parse them. I am **not** looking for a proof to the following statement; just guidance as to where to start or what the shape of a proof for it looks like.

Prove that a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded if and only if there is $M ∈ \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x| ≤ M$ for all $x ∈ A$.

I know something is bounded if it has an upper and lower bound, and I have read axioms of fields and the definition of the absolute value.

Comment: That looks like the **definition** of a bounded subset of $\Bbb R$ to me. So, presumably you have a **different** definition of bounded set that you are working from. Surely, the first thing to do is to write down that definition, and then check to see whether a set satisfying the given criterion satisfies it.

Comment: thank you, that makes a lot of sense, but there is no other definition. the text above is all that was provided.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: another definition might be like this: a non-empty set $S$ is bounded if there exist numbers $m, M$ such that $m\leq s\leq M$ for all $s\in S$. Your definition is simpler and my preferred one.